# AJAX JQUERY JSP can't connect to server. INSERT data INTO DB

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, jsp

I've tried my best but i wasnt able to make it work. I hope someone out there will be able to help me. I've already spent a lot of time here. My passing of data using POST is working but now i am receiving an Internal Server Error.

JQuery:

```
$("#submit").click(function(){
                var lname = $("#lname").val();
                var fname = $("#fname").val();
                var mi = $("#mi").val();
                var birthdate = $("#birthdate").val();
                var uname = $("#uname").val();
                var pword = $("#pword").val();              
                var cpword = $("#cpword").val();
                if (lname == " " || fname == " " || mi == " " || birthdate == " " || uname == " " || pword == " " || cpword == " " || lname == "" || fname == "" || mi == "" || birthdate == "" || uname == "" || pword == "" || cpword == ""){ }
                else {
                    var data = 
                    {
                        'lname':lname.toString(),
                        'fname':fname.toString(),
                        'mi':mi.toString(),
                        'birthdate':birthdate.toString(),
                        'uname':uname.toString(),
                        'pword':pword.toString()
                    };
                    $.ajax({
                        type:"POST",
                        url:"insert.jsp",
                        data: data,
                        success:function(){alert("success");},
                        error:function(xhr, status, error) { alert('error: ' + error);}
                    });
                }
            });
```

Html:

```
<body>
    <form name="registration" id="registration" method="POST" action="">
        <input type="text" id="lname" placeholder="Lastname" required><br/>
        <input type="text" id="fname" placeholder="Firstname" required><br/>
        <input type="text" id="mi" placeholder="Middle Initial" required><br/>
        <input type="date" id="birthdate" placeholder="Birthdate" required><br/>
        <input type="text" id="uname" placeholder="Username" required><br/>
        <input type="password" id="pword" placeholder="Password" required><br/>
        <input type="password" id="cpword" placeholder="Confirm Password" required><br/>
        <input type="submit" id="submit"><br/>
    </form>
</body>
```

JSP:

```
Connection conn = null;
String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
String dbName = "activity5_db";
String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
String userName = "root";
String password = "";
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url + dbName, userName, password);
        Statement st = conn.createStatement();

        String lname = request.getParameter("lname");    
        String fname = request.getParameter("fname");    
        String mi = request.getParameter("mi");    
        String birthdate = request.getParameter("birthdate");    
        String uname = request.getParameter("uname");    
        String pword = request.getParameter("pword");    
        st.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO `user_tbl`(lastname,firstname,middlei,date_of_birth,username,password) VALUES ('"+ lname +"', '"+ fname +"', '"+ mi +"', '"+ birthdate +"', '"+ uname +"', '"+ pword +"')");

        conn.close();
response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
```

I dont know if the error is my syntax of JSP or something else. Anyone would be able to make it clear on me how to use JSP would be appreciated. Tnx!

Comment: When you have an Internal Server Error, look in the server logs to find out what the error is!

Comment: **Danger**: You are vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Comment: Im sorry im new to this. i dont even know how :( i guess ill google how to now. it doesnt show any errors. it just prompts error internal server error. since im just calling the JSP on other file. Im not yet uploading or will do anything with this. im still learning on how to before doing a lot of stuff

Comment: Why are you REDIRECTING(response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");)  since you are sending request using AJAX?

Comment: it does nothing i tried to remove it. same error...

Comment: i tried to remove starting from "conn to the end" then no error.. is there something wrong with my syntax?